# Vue JS 2 Axios Post request Form with Phalcon

Tags: vuejs2, axios, phalcon

I try to POST form with Axios. But I dont know why, Need 2 request post to store data to database.

**Form**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-raised" @click="editUser();">Save</button>
```

**Axios POST**

```
editUser: function(formData){
    var formData = vmUser.toFormData(vmUser.userData);
    axios.post("/admin/users/update", formData)
    .then( function(response){
        vmUser.userData = {
                user_id: $("#user_id").val(),
                ...
        }
```

**toFormData method**

```
toFormData: function(obj){
                    var form_data = new FormData();
                    for ( var key in obj ) {
                        form_data.append(key, obj[key]);
                    } 
                    return form_data;
                },
```

**Phalcon Controller**

```
$data = [
        'result' => 'ok',
        'error' => '',
        'message' => '',
];
        $user_id = $this->request->getPost("user_id");
        $user = SyswebUsers::findFirstByUserId($user_id);
        $user->user_name = $this->request->getPost("user_name");
        ...
        if (!$user->save()) {
            $data['error'] = 'error';
            $data['message'] = 'Failed!';
        }
        else
        {
            $data['message'] = 'Success!';

        } 
$this->sendJson($data);
```

Comment: For me it's not clear your question: do you want to know why do you have to use `$this->request->getPost()`?

Comment: getPost() is for getting data from input form.

Comment: and your question is?